# Powershell read lots of text files, filter information and write into other text file as one row

Tags: powershell, text-files

For the upcoming Windows 10 Migration i need a list of MAC-addresses, IP-Addresses and computer name. Now we have lots of text files automaticly generated while users logon to the network. These text files contain the needed information. Now i want this information combined into one file.

This the the code so far.

```
$p = @("Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . :","IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . :","Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . :")
Get-ChildItem d:\pc\ -Filter *.txt |Get-Content |Select-String -Pattern $p |
```

But the output gives something like this:

```
Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Computername
Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : MAC-address
IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : IP-Address(Bevorzugt) 
Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
```

But i would like this output:

Computername Mac-Address IP-Adress

The 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0 addresses should be filtered out, because those are the Tunneladapter, this information is not needed. It would be enough to have the output of one file in one Row, so i could filter using excel.

At this moment i have about 2000 text files.

Example of file content:

```
10681EU;KREIS;Vico;\\DSFW1 

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Neue Verbindungen werden nicht gespeichert.


Status       Lokal     Remote                    Netzwerk

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           F:        \\i6633_nw\vol1\daten     Microsoft Windows Network
OK           J:        \\i6633_nw\vol1\prog      Microsoft Windows Network
OK           K:        \\keltenring1\vol1        Microsoft Windows Network
OK           N:        \\52.0.13.25\Kreisarchiv  Microsoft Windows Network
OK           O:        \\i4811_nw_gw\vol1        Microsoft Windows Network
OK           P:        \\giga\vol1               Microsoft Windows Network
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgefhrt.


Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10681EU
   Prim„res DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : kreis.lan
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : kreis.lan

Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 1C-6F-65-92-DE-06
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 52.0.103.215(Bevorzugt) 
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 52.0.1.1
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 52.0.13.199
                                       52.0.13.200
   NetBIOS ber TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Tunneladapter LAN-Verbindung* 9:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-6zu4-Adapter
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter LAN-Verbindung* 11:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
```

Comment: Can u give 2 examples of your files content ?

Comment: Added example. All the file look the same, only the amount of mappings in the first sector are different.

Comment: Couldn't you create a `PSCustomObject` with your required parameters? This object you could then format to a table.

Comment: I never done that and somehow i don't be able to find any useful information i can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to create an `ArrayList` of objects representing your data.

1) Create `ArrayList` that will hold the merged data from all files

2) Read files from directory using `Get-ChildItem`

3) Create a `psobject` with 3 properties + populate the properties with data using `-notlike` and `-match` operators.

Assumption: There is only 1 valid IP address/HostName/Physical Address per file.

```
$all = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {

    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PhysicalAddress -Value ($content | where-object {($_ -notlike "*00-00-00-00-00*" -and $_ –match "Physikalische Adresse")} | foreach-object{$_.Split(":")[1].Trim()} | Select -First 1)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hostname -Value ($content | where-object {($_ –match "HostName")} | foreach-object{$_.Split(":")[1].Trim()} | Select -First 1)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value ($content | where-object {($_ –match "IPv4-Adresse")} | foreach-object{$_.Split(":")[1].Trim()} | Select -First 1)
    $all.Add($obj)
}

$all | Format-List
```

Output (array of):

```
PhysicalAddress : 1C-6F-65-92-DE-06
Hostname        : 10681EU
IPAddress       : 52.0.103.215
```